# Capturar o valor de uma célula da tabela e salvar em uma variável via jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabela-html

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">teste</td>
      <td id="teste" name="teste" class="teste">1</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

preciso pegar o valor do `td` por jQuery e salvar em um *array*, no meu código tem mais linhas a tabela, eu resumi aqui

```
'teste' : jQuery('#teste').val()
```

estou fazendo assim, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o elemento utilizado no seletor não é um elemento de um form, você não consegue pegar valor com o .val(). Utilize

```
jQuery('#teste').text()
```

Veja no código abaixo:

```js
console.log(jQuery("#teste").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td scope="row">teste</td>
     <td id="teste" name="teste" class="teste">1</td>   
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigada